# My employment contract as a highly skilled migrant ends; what now?

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, netherlands

I'm employed by a Dutch institution after having been granted a work (and residence) permit as a "highly skilled migrant" a couple of years ago. My contract will be up in several months. While it's possible I will want to move abroad, I might end up not wanting to do so, or wanting to do so only a while after my current contract is up. My residence permit - based on my employment - expires 2 days after my contract.

My questions are:

- What's my status, once that happens, if I do nothing?
- How long can I stay in the Netherlands with no further arrangements after my contract and residence permit expiration, without it being illegal/punishable?
- Do I/can I get some kind of grace period to look for another employer?
- If I need to do something to legally extend my stay, what can I do (other than through a new employer)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I know - which is also summarized by [this page](http://www.iamexpat.nl/read-and-discuss/career/articles/losing-your-job-expat-netherlands).

- There seems to be an **automatic 3-month grace period** for looking for another employer (assuming you weren't fired for inappropriate behavior etc.)
- It is recommended to contact the [IND](https://ind.nl/en?pk_campaign=header&pk_kwd=taal-selectie-en) (Immigration and Naturalization Service) close to when the contract expires to claim eligibility for the new employment search period and state your intention to make use of it - even though it's supposed to be automatic.
- You may be eligible to unemployment benefits - but you must apply for those with the [UWV](https://www.uwv.nl/overuwv/english/index.aspx) (Employment Insurance Agency).
- If you find a new employer within the search period, you'll continue to benefit from the 30% tax break (but it's not clear to me whether you'll "lose months" due to the 3 months of unemployment or whether the 7-year period would be extended by the duration of your search).
- If you do not find a job within the grace period you're in deep trouble, so look for more information (which I don't have) on what to do in this case; you may want to leave before that happens.

Some more (less-specific) information [here](http://www.expatica.com/nl/visas-and-permits/When-your-residence-permit-expires-or-you-want-to-leave-the-Netherlands_108416.html). Also note that the grace period seems to be a result of legislation changes from last year, so you should always make sure the information you're reading anywhere is up-to-date with legislative changes (including the advice here).